# Slow write performance of MariaDb with data directory outside root partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, performance, raspberry-pi, mariadb

My application suffers from slow write actions into a MariaDB when the data directory of the server is on a different disk partition then the root partition.

I use a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Buster as OS.

**The setup of slow performance:**

- The SD card is divided into three partitions: first boot, second root, and third data.
- The root partition is set to read only, but shows slow performance with read-write performance too.
- I copied the MariaDb data directory by means of rsync to a location on the data partition and adjusted the mariaDB config file accordingly.

**Setup of normal performance:**

- As soon as I change the data directory in the MariaDb config file to a directory on the root partition, the speed of saving data in the database is as fast as expected.

**For comparison:** When the data directory is not on the root partition, the average time to write my data is dramatically increased by 14 seconds. I do not write much data, and usually it may take a round 1 second or even less.

Comment: Do you use the same filesystem on both partitions? Is the data partition aligned to SD card block size?

Comment: Yes, I use the same filesystem (ext4, mounted with option noatime). How do I know/assure that the partition is aligned to the block size of the card?

Comment: See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326632/disk-full-while-importing-a-large-sql-dump/326633#326633)